# How can I manually initiate the creation of a home folder for an AD user in Windows?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, folder-redirection, home-directory

I have an AD environment with Windows 2008R2 Server where a few Windows 7 machines use FolderRedirection . Sometimes I need to re-initiate the homefolder creation process, but the only way I've found to get the folder to be recreated on login is to delete and recreate the account.

Is there a way to manually initiate the process that happens on the initial login without recreating the account?

Comment: `1.` Why don't you post a question about the actual problem rather than asking how you can make a poor workaround work. `2.` Your method is a poor workaround. `3.` They have some (as yet unnamed) problem with Folder Redirection and your solution is to delete the user account?

Comment: I realize it's a poor workaround, I edited the question to focus more on account creation. Regardless of what the problem is, knowing how to initiate the homefolder creation process is useful for me.

Comment: Usually there's a check if the folder exists, if it doesn't, it's created.  Log the user out, rename the existing home folder to whatever.old and then have the user log in.

Comment: @jlehtinen - I tried doing that originally, figuring it would just recreate the folder. It doesn't, the user logs in and gets a temporary profile.

Comment: Is the Home folder setting configured as `\\server\share\%username%`?

Comment: @joeqwerty - Are you referring to the `Home folder` setting on the user's `Profile` tab?

The radio button for `Connect` is selected.

The drive letter is `H:`

The `To:` field is `\\server\share\%username%`.

`%username%` is the literal username, not the variable.

Comment: Here's hat I've found will cause the folder to be recreated: 1. Remove the Home folder setting from the user object and apply. 2. Wait for AD replication (which should be near instantaneous between DC's in the same site). 3. Reconfigure the Home folder setting on the user object. 4. Wait for AD replication (which should be near instantaneous between DC's in the same site). 5. Log on as the user. - I've just tested this and it works. - As an aside, you can verify the value of the setting by looking at the  homeDrive and homeDirectory attributes on the user object in ADSIEdit.

Comment: @joeqwerty - Awesome, that works. It's almost frustratingly simple. Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I thought of one more case I'm not sure of. I have another share for homefolders that are used only on specific computers in a more secure area. These secure homefolders aren't set in the user's profile, but are set via GPO using loopback. Any idea for that case? Maybe I should make another question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's hat I've found will cause the folder to be recreated:

1. Remove the Home folder setting from the user object and apply.
2. Wait for AD replication (which should be near instantaneous between DC's in the same site).
3. Reconfigure the Home folder setting on the user object.
4. Wait for AD replication (which should be near instantaneous between DC's in the same site).
5. Log on as the user.

I've just tested this and it works. As an aside, you can verify the value of the setting by looking at the homeDrive and homeDirectory attributes on the user object in ADSIEdit.

Comment: Any ideas on this:  I have another share for homefolders that are used only on specific computers in a more secure area. These secure homefolders aren't set in the user's profile, but are set via GPO using loopback. Any idea for that case? Maybe I should make another question?